# use custom ompl instead of ros own ompl

Tags: ros, library, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there
I would like to develop some path planning algorithms along with ompl, however, it is not easy to use the ros build-in ompl. I would like to build the ompl from source in case of easy revision. I have another package that use ompl (which is : ompl_move_base) , how should I write in CMakeList.txt file so as to use the ompl in /usr/local instead of the one in /ros/indigo/ ?

Many many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250956/use-custom-ompl-instead-of-ros-own-ompl/) by [chaoqunzhuoyue](https://answers.ros.org/users/22062/chaoqunzhuoyue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps the instructions on the [Building Common MoveIt! Dependencies from Source in Catkin - Open Motion Planning Library (OMPL)](http://moveit.ros.org/install/source/dependencies/) page of the MoveIt documentation site could help.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0